# How to don't save equals String in Firebase firestore for Flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm reading a QR Code in my app and save it in firebase, but I need to save it just one time, if it is different save, but if it is equal there is no need to save.

this is my code

```
await Firestore.instance
       .collection("lockers")
       .document()
       .setData({"numero_serie": _numeroSerie});
}
```

[myapp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HG7I9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct Answer

```
final QuerySnapshot result = await Future.value(Firestore.instance
    .collection("lockers")
    .where("numero_serie", isEqualTo: "$_numeroSerie")
    .limit(1)
    .getDocuments());

final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = result.documents;
    if (documents.length == 1) {
    confirmacao(context);
    } else {
    await Firestore.instance
     .collection("lockers")
     .document()
     .setData({"numero_serie": _numeroSerie});
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A normal `setData` will insert value irrespective of what the value of your QR code is. You need to perform a `get` and check if the value is already present and then insert the data.

Check https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore for reading data and then setting it in Firestore.